# How Would You Create This Decorative Border Made with Text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, borders

How would you guys create this border?  Right now I'm creating individual text frames for each side of the border, but I'm sure there's an easier way.

I'm using Illustrator CC 2017 by the way.

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a rectangle where you would like your border and use the Type On A Path Tool to type along that path. Type your text and copy/paste as needed.

You can read more about typing on a path in Illustrator here:

- [How to create type on a path in Illustrator - Adobe Support](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-type-path.html)

Or if you want to be clever about it you can use either of the methods I describe in [In Illustrator endlessly repeat a string of text on a path](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/70402/52050), basically either:

1. Create a pattern brush out of your text (converting to outlines first) and apply it to the rectangle.

   Or,
2. Use a transform effect to repeat the text then duplicate and rotate for each edge of the page.

Typing on a path is probably much quicker and easier though.

Comment: Awsesome, thanks for the answering. Not sure why I didn't think about type on a path tool.